# Rendered strange Obj symbols in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a newbie and I need some help:) I use Vue JS and Vuetify.

Trying to display some html with a couple of 'p' tags from data via v-html in Vue JS. But there are strange OBJ symbols.
It looks like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOLZg.png)

Here is my code:

```
data() {
    return {
         content: "<p>Разогрев голоса и вокальные упражнения — это то, что объединяет вокалистов всех уровней: от начинающих до мировых звёзд.</p><p>Наша программа для распевок – абсолютно универсальный￼ инструмент. Он подойдёт вокалистам любого уровня, с любым типом голоса, любым диапазоном, а также для любого музыкального стиля.￼￼</p><p>Все что нужно, это знать как его настроить, как им пользоваться и правильно оценивать свои силы. ￼￼В ближайших видео мы расскажем об упражнениях для вокалистов разного уровня подготовки. Но это не строгие правила. На самом деле, вы сможете придумывать свои способы применения этого приложения.￼￼ Также вы можете изучать только те уроки, которая подходит именно вам.￼</p><p>Удачи и добро пожаловать в это музыкальное приключение!</p>￼"
         }
    }
```

Noticed it appears only if it's more than one 'p' tag. But without tags at all
it is the same.

```
<div v-html="content"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please show us true code (As I see, on image text is on Russian while in example it is on English)?

Comment: Ok. I edited post

Comment: I [see some `obj` symbols](http://prntscr.com/u7a4tt) in your input text. Vue shows them.

Comment: I don't know is it important, but i also simplified my code. Actually, i have an array of 'lessons' objects and 'content' is a key

Comment: hmm.. i can't see it. Checked it in Google Chrome. Here I see only whitespaces, but how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Ivan Didyk was right. I just delete some symbols where it appears and rewrite.

Hope it will help someone)